# Getting 404 when trying to access js file

Tags: tomcat, spring-mvc, http-status-code-404

I am using Spring as a Rest Server and all the application is managed by the client.

I've copied my UI file to webapps\ folder:

```
webapps\<MY APP>
    -> scripts (where I have my js files)
        -> directives 
        -> services
    -> styles 
    -> views
    -> META-INF
    -> WEB-INF
    index.html
```

The problem is when navigating to `http://localhost:8080/devstage-1.0/` I am getting index.html back but when it tries to fetch the js dependencies which are inside directories I am getting 404 back.

```
GET http://localhost:8080/devstage-1.0/scripts/services/dictionary.js 404 (Not Found)
```

From my knowledge Spring manages only files inside WEB-INF. Is there some other configuration that I have to do to make these files accessible?

Comment: Are you sure that the js files have the correct filesystem permissions to be readable by the user running Tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue and it was my typo.

I used the copy target in Grunt and instead of /** which copies recursively both file and folders I put /* which copies only one level meaning the folders (with out content) and files.

Answer (score 0):

In your Spring configuration XML file:

```
<mvc:resources
    mapping="/**"
    location="/"
/>
```

as described [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-static-resources).